# Populate dropdownlist from a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a drop down list which contains 3 values:

- Male
- Female
- Unspecified

Basically in my view, when I selected with male, female or unspecified, I want to change the data that I have in another combo box, e.g. the male users, the female users and the users who haven't given their gender.

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

foreach (User user in ctspc.db.AllUsers.ToList())
{
    users.Add(DAL.Getusers(user.UserId));
}
```

So here I get all the users, my problem is I need to use LINQ to sort out which type of gender I need to search, that bit I can handle, the problem I am having is that I am unable to retrieve the drop down list value.

I tried:

```
var x = Request.Params["cboGender"];
```

But I assume because the page hasn't loaded yet, it isn't able to get what the current value is, so basically what I am trying to do is have it so depending on the value in the list box at the time, I want it to recall my Create method and keep getting the selected value and updating the new list box.

Here I have the cshtml code

```
<select name="cboGender">
    @foreach (var Gender in ViewBag.Genders)
    {
        <option value="@Gender.GenderId">@Gender.Name</option>
    }
</select>

<select name="cboUser">
    @foreach (var User in ViewBag.UsersByGender)
    {
        <option value="@User.UserId">@User.Username</option>
    }
</select>
```

Any help on how I can do this would be great.

Comment: Is using jQuery acceptable? You can handle the dropdownlist's change event to call a method using AJAX and return a list of users based on the selected gender, then repopulate the second dropdownlist

Comment: I was kind of hoping to avoid using JavaScript because of Security and Validation issues.

Comment: Not sure what _Security and Validation_ issues you have, but in that case, I think yoru only option is to submit the form once you select the gender, then in the post method, create the collection of users based on the selected gender and return a new view (like a 2 step 'wizard')

Comment: Jessica, javascript is the way to go here..no decent web site nowadays gets away without using javascript...

Comment: Also are you specifically trying to avoid using _javascript_, or is it the AJAX request that you're trying to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then, you can try one of the following methods to retrieve data.

e.g.

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction(string cboGender)
```

or try using

```
 string Gender= Request.QueryString["cboGender"];
```

or

```
 [HttpPost] 
 public ActionResult SubmitAction(FormCollection collection)
 {
    // Get Post Params Here
    string var1 = collection["cboGender"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no other way to do this without js. 
Oh, maybe you can create a button to sumbit the form,so your server side can get the value,
 Request.Params["cboGender"]  will effective. then filter user,render the page(it means refresh and bad experience ), is that your want?

I guess you used to do with asp.net WebForm.
In fact , WebForm framework also encapsulated with much js(JQuery) code.
the best way is : use ajax to post the genderId to server method like belowe

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetUserByGenderId(int? genderId)
        {
            var list =  AllUsers.Where(a => a.genderId == genderId);// filter user
            return Json(list);// return  serialized json or 
            return Json(list.Select(a=>new { a.UserName,a.UserId }).Tolist());

        }
```

and the ajax would receive this json to render the cboUser.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, but based on the way you've asked the question I think the easiest would be to do something along these lines:

1: Put a new combo-box into the page for each group of users, and hide them by default (note here I'm not a `foreach` like you are but that's just for brevity of the example):

```
<select id="cboGender" name="cboGender">
  <option id="Male">Male</option>
  <option id="Female">Female</option>
  <option id="Unspecified">Unspecified</option>
</select>

<select id="cboMale" class="user-combo" name="user" hidden>
  <option id="1">Oscar</option>
  <option id="2">Leo</option>
</select>

<select id="cboFemale" class="user-combo" name="user" hidden>
  <option id="3">Kristy</option>
  <option id="4">Wendy</option>
</select>

<select id="cboUnspecified" class="user-combo" name="user" hidden>
  <option id="5">Jamie</option>
  <option id="6">Charlie</option>
</select>
```

2: Use jQuery to listen for changes to the "cboGender" combo box, then show the appropriate combo box in response:

```
var onGenderChanged = function() {
  var gender = $genders.val();

  // Hide all gender combo boxes...
  $userCombos.hide();

  // ... then show the one corresponding to the selection
  $("#cbo" + gender).show();
};
```

[Here's a JSBin which shows a working implementation.](http://jsbin.com/nogoxoyo/1/edit?html,js,output)

The advantage of doing this is it saves you a "round-trip" to get the gender specific users each time the user changes.

Another alternative would be to load the users with an AJAX request when a gender is selected, but that's a bit more involved.

HTH

Comment: Sorry only just reloaded and saw your comment about avoiding JavaScript :-|